# Can non contributors attend Pot Luck lunches

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, socializing

We are having a Pot Luck lunch with people bringing in food. I did not bring any food. But our office assistant has emailed everyone saying lunch will start promptly at Noon. What is the usual etiquette here? Is it normal for people to come even if they didn't bring food, or is it expected that only contributors will come?

Comment: Run to a nearby shop.  Buy a large bag of chips or something.

Comment: UA, I've edited your post to prevent it from being closed as too localized.  We can't tell you what your particular company expects here, but we can address industry norms.  All that said, it would be helpful if you would [edit] into the question where you are located and something about the company -- small start-up verses 500-person site might have different answers.

Comment: Thank You. Its too late now to bring anything but everyone's welcome to the lunch I believe.

Comment: Just don't take any left-overs unless there is an offer and no one else accepts.

Comment: A large pizza with everting on it will work for you..

Comment: Why don't you just order a big-@$$ pu-pu platter from the nearest Chinese food restaurant and have it delivered? Who doesn't like Chinese food?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always attend. Sometimes I bring food. Sometimes not. It all evens out in the end. In fact usually it does not even out. Usually there is too much food.

Comment: Thank You. Its too late now to bring anything but everyone's welcome to the lunch I believe.

Comment: I believe that it's always good to actively participate in these events, and sometimes (when my dish didn't turn out right) everyone is better off without my contribution.

Answer (score 9):

In my experience (US technology companies, some small and some large), these gatherings are primarily social events organized by the attendees (not by corporate higher-ups).  In that regard, you should think of it as similar to any other casual pot-luck, like one organized by friends.

This one takes place in the workplace, so there is an additional expectation to attend -- you're already in the office, after all, so if you don't show up you risk being seen as anti-social.  (How much of a *problem* that is depends on the nature of your relationship with your peers.)  Unless the pot-luck was organized by management, don't read too much into the email from the office assistant; most likely somebody asked her to send out a message with the time and she's just being helpful.  Unless there's been some other communication about this, don't read her email as signifying mandatory attendance.

If you want to attend you have a couple options.  First, if there's a store nearby, run out before lunch and pick up something -- chips, cookies, soft drinks, whatever's practical.  If you can't do that, you can show up and mingle; you don't have to heap food on a plate right away.  Or if it looks like you need a plate of food to fit in, take something small to satisfy the social convention.  Toward the end of the gathering, if there's plenty of food (usually true in my experience), you can take more then.

Finally, if the gathering *is* official in some way -- management told you they expect everybody to come but they want you to bring the food -- then you should show up even if you don't bring anything.  Whether and how much you eat is something you should then figure out based on the mood in the room; if you're with a bunch of grumpy coworkers who feel they've been ordered to buy lunch then maybe you want to skip eating, but if people are enthusiastic, brought too much food anyway, and are encouraging you to eat, go ahead and do so.

Answer (score 3):

Most places don't check to see if you brought something, but people kind of know as people take credit for the delicous things they brought. If you don't bring something once and eat, it is usually not a problem. If you never bring anything, they may still let you eat, but the people who are bringing the food will decide that you are a jerk. I fonly the women in your office are bringing things, they will decide you are a bigger jerk.